# Not understandable nullpointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
private void calculateTotalValue() {
    DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel) tableDetail.getModel();
    double total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<dtm.getRowCount();i++){
        total =total+(double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 4);
    }
    totallbl.setText(Double.toString(total));
}
```

`total =total+(double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 4);` this line throws the `NullPointerException` 
But I can't understand why it is happening?

Comment: Post your logs here, check your `tableDetail.getModel()` basically the `dtm` object  and this could be  `dtm.getValueAt(i, 4)`  returning null.

Comment: @Ivar In that case `dtm` would be null and the line above would already throw a NPE. Should be `dtm.getValueAt(i, 4)` that returns null and throws a NPE when casting to double.